# can't animate an image slider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, carousel

I'm new to javascript/jquery, and I'm building an image slider. I can't seem to get the images to animate. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

What I've been trying to do is to get the active slide then slide the next sibling and animate it, but all I get in result is that the first image animate then it stops.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/6qntgg5z/

```
<div id="container">
<header>
    header is here
</header>
<div id="carousel">
<div class="sliderbuttons">
    <input type="button" name="next" id="next" value=" > ">
    <input type="button" name="next" id="prev" value=" < ">
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg" alt="image1" class="slide active">
        <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/green-Rice-1600x900.jpg" alt="image2" class="slide">
        <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg" alt="image3" class="slide">
    </div>


</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background: black;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    color: white;
}

#carousel {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 100%;

}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.sliderbuttons {
    }

#prev,#next {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 148, 41, 0.68);
    box-shadow: 2px white;
    border:none;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
/*  font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
*/  padding:10px;
    top:15%;
    width: 10%;
    /*making the prev,next on top of content*/
    z-index: 2;
}
#prev {
    left:0;
}
#next {
    right:0;
        }

.active {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(animateSlider(), 5000);
    });
    //configuration
    var currentSlide=activeSlide();
    var slides=$("#carousel .slides .slide");

    //get active slide index
    function activeSlide(){
        var activeSlide=$("#carousel .slides .active").index();
        return activeSlide;
    }

    function animateSlider() {
        var $current=slides.eq(activeSlide());
        var $next= $(".slides img:first");
        $next.addClass('active');

        $current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, 

            function () {
                    $current.removeClass('active');
                    $current.css({opacity: 1.0});
                });
```

Comment: It seems there is a conflict between the index and the .slides length, I don't know how to work over that problem, any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should continue your approach of trying to figure out and design your own version of this! but unslider is very handy for this is you're in a time crunch.

Comment: I know couple of image sliders, but I'm trying to get familiar with jquery first before checking out the other sliders and how they're coded. Thanks though, I'll give a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this fiddle (does what you need but has other flaws i think). in your html you used the '<' and '>' characters as your button text, this breaks the flow of the html so you should instead use character codes:
`<` becomes `&lt;` and
`>` becomes `&gt;` [www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

also your js was missing a closing `}` and the jsfiddle was missing aa jquery library call (I wish jsfiddle would make it faster to integrate libraries). hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){ animateSlider() }, 5000);
});
//configuration
var currentSlide = activeSlide();
var slides = $("#carousel .slides .slide");

//get active slide index
function activeSlide(){
 var activeSlide=$("#carousel .slides .active").index();
 return activeSlide;
}

function animateSlider() {
//remove active class from previous element and assign it to the current one then animate it using animate() function
    var $current=slides.eq(activeSlide());
    var $next= $(".slides img:first");
        
    $next.addClass('active');
    
    $current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function () {
                $current.removeClass('active');
                $current.css({opacity: 1});
            });
}
```

```css
html,body {
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100%;
}

header {
 background: black;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 1.5em;
 color: white;
}

#carousel {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 45%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 height: 100%;

}

.slide {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}
.sliderbuttons {
 }

#prev,#next {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(255, 148, 41, 0.68);
 box-shadow: 2px white;
 border:none;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
/* font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
*/ padding:10px;
    top:15%;
 width: 10%;
 /*making the prev,next on top of content*/
 z-index: 2;
}
#prev {
 left:0;
}
#next {
 right:0;
  }

.active {
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <header>
        header is here
    </header>
    <div id="carousel">
    <div class="sliderbuttons">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="&gt;">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="prev" value="&lt;">
        </div>
        <div class="slides">
            <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg" alt="image1" class="slide active">
            <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/green-Rice-1600x900.jpg" alt="image2" class="slide">
            <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg" alt="image3" class="slide">
        </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! The animation function works but it only slides the first image, but at least it keeps sliding. Now, I have to find a way to make all the images slides not just one.

Comment: no problem. have spent a long time wrestling with different sliders. not sure why your buttons don't seem to work but the easiest solution I think would be to use jquery `$('#next').trigger('click')` in the set interval function as a replacement for the majority of this code.

Comment: I've created a function that makes the buttons work. I just didn't put them in here..but I'll look into your suggestion. it would be easier than my original code.